# Hyperledger Indy ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I'm working on this https://github.com/hyperledger/education repository and 
When i try to run ./manage up, i'm getting this error .

```
ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try running :

```
docker system prune
```

and now run

```
./manage up
```

and it will start working.

Comment: WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all dangling images
  - all dangling build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] N

Comment: WARNING: This will remove all containers from your docker. This answer needs to be added as a warning in main body.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are encountering is suggesting you have a network address conflict.
run following list all the docker network running currently on your machine.

`docker network ls`

Then remove networks

```
docker network rm <networkId>
```